# (Swift) Get usage data from other apps through the battery page in settings

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an app where it tracks the usage of other apps. I already know that this is impossible to do by directly getting usage data from apps that do not belong to you. I am wondering if there is any way to access the `battery page in the settings` app by using the code in swift.

[image]

All I want is to be able to read the data for hours used and use that data in my app. I know this is probably a stretch, but is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: impossible as i know

Comment: Apple is very strict on it's privacy rules. It's not possible to read that kind of data in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to read this data directly.

There is an app on the App Store which has a hacky workaround. It requires users to take a screenshot of the battery usage settings page. The app grabs this photo from the user's photo library and uploads it to their servers where it is processed (using image analysis and OCR). They use this information to estimate how much each app is used.